# DIV absolute position works in IE, Chrome but not FF

Tags: css

I wanted to set a 2-tone, full-window background to my page:

```
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 50%; height: 100%; top: 0%; left: 0%; z-index:-1;background-color: 96C3FF"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 50%; height: 100%; top: 0%; left: 50%; z-index:-1;background-color: BEC0C2"></div>
<div id="mainDiv">...</div>
</body>
```

This works great on Chrome and IE8 but not on FF3. I thought maybe I need to set the height on body to 100%, but that doesn't help.

If I remove the z-index, they're visible properly on all 3 browsers but drawn on top of mainDiv... and setting mainDiv's z-index to 1 doesn't do anything.

I didn't think any of this was that unusual... any ideas?

Comment: It works fine in FireFox 3.5 atleast.

Comment: Works for me in FF 3.0.15, too.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in Firefox for me too, but there are some other things you could look at, although unrelated to this problem:

- Colors in HEX notation should start with an #. So 96C3FF would be #96C3FF
- You could use right: 0; instead of left: 50%;